# IE renders a Rails loop twice - all other browsers render once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer

Here is a simple loop written in `.html.erb`.

For each `portfolio_item` we create a box in a 3-column grid. Note that `<div class="portfolioOptions">` is hidden but appears `onmouseover`, covering `<span id="title">`.

In IE 7, 8, and 9, for each `@portfolio_item`, I am getting a box that functions followed by a **second empty box!**. Even IE's HTML source only shows one box.

```
<div class="gridRow">
    <% @portfolio_items.each do |item| %>
    <%= link_to params.except(:controller,:action).merge(:controller=>"portfolio_items", :action=>"show", :id=>item.id) do %>
    <div class="boxHalf portfolioBox" id="<%= item.id %>">
        <div class="portfolioItem">
            <% if item.url.present? && item.url_type == "vid" %>
              <%= item.vid_thumb.html_safe %>
            <% else %>
              <%= image_tag item.item.url(:medium) %>
            <% end %>
            <div class="text" title="<%= item.title %>">
                <span id="title_<%= item.id %>"><%= item.title %></span>
                <div class="portfolioOptions" id="option_<%= item.id %>">
                    <%= link_to 'Show', item, :class=>"blueButton" %>
                    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_portfolio_item_path(item, :source=>"index"), :class=>"blueButton" %>
                    <%= link_to 'Delete', item, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete, :class=>"blueButton" %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Relatively minor additional problem - the `portfolioOptions` mouseover doesn't display in IE, but I'll leave that as a subordinate to the double-box problem.

Comment: Could you try to minimize the example to something that would be easier to reproduce and to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try validating the HTML that comes out of this. You wrap the div inside a `link_to`, and it contains links itself. Is that valid html? As far as i know a `<a>` element cannot contain a block-level element, or another `<a>` again.

Not sure how that should behave either.

Comment: I don't know what mechanism IE was using to render these boxes twice, but removing that encompassing `<a>` tag was enough to prevent this from happening again. Thanks!